# ng-click not firing function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and originally had this working when everything was inside one file. Now I am trying to use partials and i am having problems. Here is my index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="JBenchApp">
<head>
    <title>Judicial Workbench</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

            if (dd < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd
            }

            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm
            }

            today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({ autoclose: true, startDate: today });
            $('#theDate').val(today);
            var $active = $('#accordion .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
            $active.find('a').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right"></span>');
            $('#accordion .panel-heading').not($active).find('a').prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>');
            $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                $('#accordion .panel-heading.active').removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
                $(e.target).prev().addClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
            });
            $('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                $(e.target).prev().removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
            });

            $('#firstWarrant').click(function () {
                $('#showLogo').hide();
                $('#typeOfCase').html('Warrant - Moritz, Jay');
                $('#warrant1').show();
                $('#warrant2').hide();
            });

            $('#secondWarrant').click(function () {
                $('#showLogo').hide();
                $('#typeOfCase').html('Warrant - Newman, Erika');
                $('#warrant2').show();
                $('#warrant1').hide();
            });

            $('.navbar-nav li').click(function (e) {
                $('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                var $this = $(this);
                if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
                    $this.addClass('active');
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        });
    </script>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="JBenchCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid black-back">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Judicial Workbench</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Min/Mandatory Chart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trial Guide</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calendar Check-in</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pull-right" ng-show="!loggedin">
                <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username" class="login-area" />
                <input type="password" name="userPassword" placeholder="Password" class="login-area" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="isLoggedIn();">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right white" ng-show="loggedin">
                <span>Welcome, Judge Mahony!</span>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right white">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block submitBtn">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog white settings"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ng-view>
            <!-- Location for partial views to be displayed-->
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
'use strict';

var JBenchApp = angular.module('JBenchApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'JBenchControllers'
]);

JBenchApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/calendar', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

Here is the controllers.js:

```
'use strict';

/** Controllers **/

var JBenchControllers = angular.module('JBenchControllers', []);

JBenchControllers.controller('JBenchCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.loggedin = false;

    $scope.isLoggedIn = function () {
        $scope.loggedin = true;
    };
});
```

Here is my calendar.html partial:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="loggedin">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Calendar here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        Case list here
    </div>

</div>
```

When i click the button that has ng-click="isLoggedIn" the "calendar here" and "case list here" row doesn't show. However, the part of my index.html file that says "Welcome, Judge Mahony!" does show and it is also dependent upon the same variable. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is an image using ng-inspector that shows two scopes. I've linked each scope to where in the code it is. How to avoid this?
[image]

Comment: It would be better if you create a jsbin with the question

Comment: Instead of posting whole code here, why don't you put it on `plunkr` or `jsfiddle` so that we can directly look into your issue.

Comment: Not sure how I would include my partial views in a jsfiddle or plnkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research on this issue the answer was to add ng-show="$parent.loggedin" to the partial that is being displayed via the routing. That then accesses the parent scope loggedin variable and all is well with the world.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AngularJS ngView documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView):

> This directive creates new scope.

So your template `calendar.html` inside the directive `ng-view` is accessing the scope of `ngView`, not accessing the scope of outside controller.

Using an object to bind will work. For example, in your controller:

```
$scope.userStatus = {
    loggedin: false
};
```

Then use `ng-show="userStatus.loggedin"` or `ng-hide="userStatus.loggedin"`.

Reference: [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: I do not understand your statement "Try to use object to bind, say user.loggedin" Can you please explain what you mean?